# How do I create a non managed Windows GUI in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, native, managed

When I create a 'Windows Forms Application', the resultant program is a managed one. Creating a 'Win32 Application' results in a native one, but when I try to add a form I'm informed that the project will be converted to CLI if I continue. How do I design a native Windows GUI with Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition? I'm probably being very silly here, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: How are you trying to 'add a form'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Reed Copsey, MFC would be the "default" way of creating a native unmanaged GUI on the Windows platform. However, MFC is not included with Visual Studio Express. Consequently, you would either need to upgrade to the full version or you could look into using a freely available C++ GUI library such as [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).

There is also [wxFormsBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/) if you want a GUI editor.

You could also go down to the "bare metal" and code right to the Win32 API, maybe take some help from the [common controls library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775493(VS.85).aspx). But you'll be entering a world of pain ;)

Comment: Ah, I see. I was hoping there'd be a non-MFC native designer. I'll look into wxWidgets or qt. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: There *is* a non-MFC native designer. It's called the Resource Editor.

Answer (score 7):

Either use MFC, WTL, or straight Win32 API. You can't use forms (or any of .NET) without switching into managed code.

- MFC is [Microsoft Foundation Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e(VS.71).aspx) - the most common C++ windows library
- WTL is [Windows Template library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library) - a better C++ windows library IMO
- Win32 is [CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679(VS.85).aspx), [DialogBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645452(VS.85).aspx), etc, everything else is a wrapper around the Win32 api.

Comment: Adding to the answer - CreateWindow and DialogBox type functions may take a dialog template resource.  You can use the resource editor to add new and edit using the graphical window editor.

Comment: What about XAML? Any specific reason there's no mention of it neither in this question nor in the other similar ones?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to avoid the managed libraries.  Most likely, this will mean using [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) for the GUI, instead of Windows Forms.  For details, see [MSDN's MFC pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx).

Unfortunately, VC++ Express Edition doesn't support MFC directly, so you'll have be more limited.  It is possible to [compile MFC projects](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/MFCinVisualStudioExpress.aspx) using the Express Edition, but you lose all of the Wizards, etc.  If you are serious about doing non-managed GUI development, you should consider upgrading to a higher level SKU.

---

Another option would be to use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) for for GUI.  It is now LGPL, so usable, for free, in even commercial C++ projects, and includes a full designer.

Comment: Thank you, but MFC isn't included with Express. I suppose I could just use wxWidgets or the like, but then that's not very 'visual'.

Comment: It may not be visual, Reed does tell you how to do write a GUI C++ app with VS 2005 Express.

Comment: @Dataflashsabot: I'd recommend considering Qt, then.  It's very nice for making native C++ GUIs, and does include a designer.  I edited my answer to reflect this option, and included a link

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the linked question. Unfortunately, that has been closed by Robert Harvey because he thinks it is a duplicate. It is not, sorry Bob.

The best library for creating xll's is http://xll.codeplex.com. You can use that to create rudimentary user interfaces using Excel macros. One example of that can be found in the ALERT.FILTER macro in [xll/error.cpp](http://xll.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/12267#134569)

Comment: Upvoting just because I absolutely hate it when mods blindly do stuff like this. My personal favorite is downvotes for being off-topic when my answer got merged with another question that was wrongly judged an "exact duplicate" (Hint: if any of the answers magically become off-topic, the question isn't a duplicate, no matter what 5 random SE users think).

Comment: To their credit, they seem to be getting better at this lately. Why they don't allow input on their decisions is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a native application framework.  For Windows this means MFC or the bare Win32 libraries.  WinForms use .NET libraries in the background and therefore need to be managed.

Answer (score 0):

Native applications don't use "forms". For a native application, you could create, for example, an MFC application. If you want it to be something like a form-based application, you can tell the wizard you want a dialog-based application, or (on the last page of the Wizard) have your view derive from CFormView instead of CView.

Alternatively, you might want to use WTL -- though that means writing essentially all your code by hand instead of using wizards and such.

Comment: The "Wizard" doesn't exist in Express Edition - unfortunately, MFC (and WTL) code is not supported (directly) in VC++ Express.

Comment: @Reed:I'll have to take your word for that. I played with the Express Edition at one point, and seemed to recall it's being able to create an MFC project, but 1) it could be my bad memory, or 2) something arising from my already having another edition installed. My recollection was that it only supported MFC in a DLL rather than statically linked, but that was the primary limitation.

Answer (score 0):

*Windows Forms is the name given to the graphical application programming interface (API) included as a part of Microsoft's .NET Framework, providing access to the native Microsoft Windows interface elements by wrapping the existing Windows API in managed code.*

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above answers explain things pretty well - if you want to look into creating a pure Win32 Native App form (no MFC/WTL etc) take a look at the tutorials here: http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/winapi/ for starters. That's the third time I've linked to this site on here, but his tutorials are very good.

Note - at this stage there's nothing "visual" about it except the result - it is all done in code, although that said I don't think it is too difficult really. It will definitely be good programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms are a GUI framework written in managed code, so you cannot use Forms in a native application.

With a native application, you have to create windows.  *Programming Windows* by Charles Petzold is the definitive how-to book for this.  It's a lot of work compared to using a good framework.  MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) is a framework for native Windows GUIs.  I don't know if it comes with VC++ Express.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that no one mentioned [JUCE](https://www.juce.com/) which can be used to build cross platform user interfaces in C++. I thought it was pretty cool. Looks like it's been expanded to support mobile devices too since I used it.

Personal and Educational licenses are free. 'Pro' and 'Indie' licenses are relatively cheap.